# Removing Duplicate rows while summing one column and preserving the other columns

Tags: r

I have dataset of a a few columns with duplicate row.( duplication based on one column by name ProjectID).

I want to remove the duplicate rows and keep just one of it.
However, each of these rows have a separate amount value against it which needs to be summed and stored for the final consolidated row.

I have used aggregate function. However it removes all other columns (by the use I know). 
Can somebody Please tell me a easier way.

the example data set is attached.
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwDc6.jpg)

Comment: See `group_by` and `summarise` in package `dplyr`

Comment: please add `dput(head(your_data,20))` to description and what you've tried

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the group_by part of dplyr or its usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a more complicated method, but worked for me.
I aggregated the amounts about the ProjectIDs using the aggregate function, storing them in a new tibble.
Further I appended this column to the original tibble as a new column. 
It didn't work exactly what I wanted to. But I was able to work out with a new column `Final_Amount` keeping the earlier `Amount` column irrelevant.

```
Duplicate_remove2 <- function(dataGP_cleaned) 
{  
#aggregating unique amounts
aggregated_amount <- aggregate(dataGP_cleaned['Amount'], by=dataGP_cleaned['ProjectID'], sum)
#finding Distinct dataset
dataGP_unique <- distinct(dataGP_cleaned, ProjectID, .keep_all = TRUE)
#changing name of the column for easy identification
aggregated_amount$Final_Amount <- aggregated_amount$Amount
#appending the list
aggregate_dataGP <- bind_cols(dataGP_unique, aggregated_amount['Final_Amount'] )
return(aggregate_dataGP)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved using `dplyr` as @PLapointe pointed out. If your dataset is called `df` then this would go as

```
df %>% 
group_by(`Project ID`, `Project No.`, `Account Head`, `Function`, `Functionary`) %>% 
summarise(cost.total = sum(Amount))
```

This should do it. You can also adjust the variables you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm facing these problems.
1. Project_Id doesn't get identified. actual column name is Project ID. So how do i use it with the space part.
2. group_by needs all these variables to be same and preserves only these?
For ex: the descriptions are different. And I need to preserve them as well.

Comment: I updated for the first part of your question. Now for the second part, do you need to `group_by` the description or are you okay with the total and you need to `join` it to the original dataset?

Comment: `Duplicate_remove <- function(dataGP_cleaned)
{
  dataGP_unique <- dataGP_cleaned %>% 
    +     group_by(`ProjectID`, `Project No.`,`Voucher`,`Account Head Description`, `Acc Head`, `Function`, `Functionary`,`Description`) %>% 
    +     summarise(cost.total = sum(Amount))
  
  return(dataGP_unique)
}`



This was the function I created.

This is the error:  *Error in group_by_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...), add = add) : 
  object 'ProjectID' not found*

Comment: You didn't need to create a function for this. If you wanted a function, then you may need to reframe the question.

Comment: Well, I thought if I get how to do this with one. I will be able to make a function on my own.
Anyway, I got one another way to do this. i'll post as my answer.
Thank you for your help.